# write after end error on express server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm working on a school assignment where we need to write a client-server application. More specifically a webshop that should be able to load products using AJAX. I make use of jquery, so I use `$.load()`.

On my index.js file (the router for the index page where all the products should be displayed), I have the following code that should handle the GET request from the AJAX call:

```
/* GET products on home page. */
router.get('/products', function(req, res, next){
  // get search query
  var parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var query = parts.query;
  var sortMode = query.sort;
  var searchTerm = query.search;

  // no search term is present
  if (!searchTerm){
    // sort by name
    if (sortMode === "alphabet"){
      db.serialize(function() {
        var resdata = "";
        db.each("SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY productname ASC", function(err, row) {
          pr = new Product(row.productid, row.productname, row.releasedate, row.publisher, row.genre, row.price, row.stock);         
          products.push(pr);
          resdata = pr.generateProductHtml();
          res.write(resdata);
        });
        res.send();
      });
    }  
});
```

for simplicity I left out all the other modes I sort by and whether a search term has been put in the search bar or not, but the code already throws the error at this bit of code.

For earch product I generate a bit of html code with the `generateProductHtml()` function and I write that html to the response. After doing that for each product, I want to send the complete html response back to the client-side and load this html in using the jquery load function I mentioned earlier.

I assume it has something to do with both `res.write(resdata)` and `res.send()`, because when I leave out the send function, the code does not seem to throw any errors, but does not send the response to the client-side code. This does not seem to make any difference when I change send() to end().

**Does anybody know what could be causing the "write after end" error in my code?** The error log does not give a lot of information except the cause probably being in this bit of code above.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

this is the error log the console gives when running the server and loading the index page:

```
GET / 200 1309.069 ms - 2526
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 4.218 ms - 4827
GET /scripts/adjustNavBar.js 200 12.590 ms - 970
GET /scripts/displayProducts.js 200 0.453 ms - 554
GET /scripts/purchaseButtonScript.js 200 0.789 ms - 282
GET /images/index/banner.jpg 200 1.142 ms - 329313
GET /products?sort=alphabet 200 1.100 ms - -
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:625:15)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:620:10)
    at Statement.<anonymous> (D:\Users\Renzo\Documents\GitHub\Client-Server-App\myapp\myapp\routes\index.js:71:15)
    at Statement.replacement (D:\Users\Renzo\Documents\GitHub\Client-Server-App\myapp\myapp\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\trace.js:19:31)
    at Statement.replacement (D:\Users\Renzo\Documents\GitHub\Client-Server-App\myapp\myapp\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\trace.js:19:31)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www "app.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Renzo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-11T09_04_38_157Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please, keep console output of the error. I asume that you are using NodeJS for server-side, right ? Are you using Express ?

Comment: Yes, I do use NodeJS for the server side with Express. I will add the console log to the question.

Comment: The `res.send` will run before your `db.each` calls finish.

Comment: Does that have something to do with me not using a callback function perhaps or the code running asynchronously?

Comment: @Renzzauw are you using node-sqlite3 ?

Comment: @HamzaFatmi yes, I am using node-sqlite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `res.end` in the **complete** callback :

```
        db.each("SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY productname ASC", 
               function(err, row) {
                        pr = new Product(row.productid, row.productname, 
                        row.releasedate, row.publisher, row.genre, 
                        row.price, row.stock);         
                        products.push(pr);
                        resdata = pr.generateProductHtml();
                        res.write(resdata);
                   }, function(err, numberOfRetreivedRows){ res.end(); });
```

see the [API docs](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete).

Comment: Perfect! That seems to have fixed the issue, I had no clue how to do this using a complete callback. Thank you!